# 'where' not finding entries given a parameter to look for in CSV data

Tags: jekyll, liquid

jekyll 2.4.0, Mac 10.12.5

```
{% for year_of_interest in (1997..2017) reversed %}
  <large_year>{{year_of_interest}}</large_year>
    {% for paper in site.data.publications |  where,'site.data.publications.Year',year_of_interest %}
            <div class="publication_card">
              <a class="article_title" href="../../{{paper.Link}}" title="{{paper.Abstract}}">{{paper.Title}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="paper_author_container">
              <span class="paper_authors">{{paper.Author | upcase}}</span>
              <br>
              <span class="journal_info">{{paper.Year}}—{{paper.Journal | upcase}}</span>
              <button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="{{paper.BibTex}}">
                BIBTEX
              </button>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The input CSV has this shape and the Year is a simple number:

```
Title,Link,Abstract,Author,BibTex,Year,Journal,SupplementalLink
```

**background:** I'm stuck! I have a CSV where each row represents publication metadata for papers from 1997 to 2016. Some years have many papers, but each year has at least 1 publication. I want a header for each year, and the publications to be posted below. Unfortunately, the where filter does not find any of the articles for a given year in the for loop.

**Current functionality:** under each  header, it shows a list of ALL publications.
**Desired:** it should only show publications where the paper.Year == year_of_interest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems here :

#### You can't filter in a loop

```
{% for paper in site.data.publications | where,'site.data.publications.Year', year_of_interest %}
```

Will not work as expected because it always returns all datas.

```
{% assign filtered = site.data.publications | where,'site.data.publications.Year', year_of_interest %}
{% for paper in filtered %}
```

Will work, but not now ...

#### Where filter filters on a key

It's not `{% site.data.publications | where,'site.data.publications.Year', year_of_interest %}`

but : `{% site.data.publications | where,'Year', year_of_interest`%}}

Nearly working ...

#### CSV datas are strings

`{{ site.data.publications[0].Year | inspect }}` returns **"1987"** and double quotes around signifies that its a string and that your filter, looking for an integer as "Year" value will never find it. You have to look for a string instead.

To cast an integer into a string you can append an empty string to it.

```
{% for year_of_interest in (1997..2017) reversed %}

  {% comment %} casting an integer to a string {% endcomment %}
  {% assign yearAsString = year_of_interest | append:"" %}

  {% comment %} filtering datas {% endcomment %}
  {% assign selectedEntries = site.data.publications | where: "Year", yearAsString %}

  {% for paper in selectedEntries %}
```

Now, it does the job.

**Notes** :

1 - Use the `| inspect` filter to debug, it's useful to determine type of value (string, integer, array, hash).

2 - You can also cast a string to an integer by adding zero to it :

```
{% assign numberAsString = "1997" %}
{{ numberAsString | inspect }} => "1997"
{% assign numberAsInteger = numberAsString | plus: 0 %}
{{ numberAsInteger | inspect }} => 1997
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! How do I enable inspect? I don't see any output when I write it into the code and run `bundle exec jekyll serve`?

Comment: No need to enable `inspect`, it works out of the box. Syntax is `{{ myVar | inspect }}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only documentation for the where filter because it is not a default liquid filter.

https://gist.github.com/smutnyleszek/9803727

`site.data.publication.Year` is an object of `site.data.publications` I believe you only need to specify `"Year"` This is case sensitive by the way.

`{% for paper in site.data.publications | where, "Year", year_of_interest %}`

Comment: no luck; this permutation has the same result. even when I change it to where:"year",year_of_interest like the gist is set up